# Why Does Command Line C# Interactive (csi.exe) Ignore Explicit Assembly Reference?

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn, nbitcoin, csi

`Microsoft (R) Visual C# Interactive Compiler version 2.9.0.63208`

`Windows 7 64 bit`

`NBitcoin 4.1.1.68`

====

[*`System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms`*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.sha256managed?view=netframework-4.7.2#examples) version 4.3.0.0 has an *`SHA256Managed`* class that I want to use in C# Interactive (*`csi.exe`*).

I added that assembly to the GAC with the *`gacutil -i [path_to_dll]`* command. I launched *`csi`* with an *`/r:[path_to_dll_dir]/System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms.dll`* command line option.

On top of that, after *`csi`* started, I also did an *`#r "[path_to_dll]"`* reference. Belt and suspenders type stuff. I know. But I guess I was hoping the overkill would force it to do the right thing.

My application uses a class from [*a third-party library*](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NBitcoin). The following code was copied pretty much verbatim from [*the third-party method*](https://github.com/MetacoSA/NBitcoin/blob/master/NBitcoin/Crypto/Hashes.cs) my app calls. If I run the following code in *`csi`*, it works fine...

```
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

byte[] b = Guid.NewGuid().ToByteArray();

var sha = new SHA256Managed(); 

byte[] c = sha.ComputeHash(b, 0, 15);
```

Now, here's the thing.  That third-party class defines a method that calls *`SHA256Managed.ComputeHash(byte[], int, int)`* exactly like the code above.

For the sake of discussion, let's refer to the third party class and method as *`Foo.m()`*.

The problem is, when I call the third party *`Foo.m()`* from *`csi`*, *`csi`* balks with...

```
Could not load type 'System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256Managed' from assembly 'System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
  + Third.Party.Foo.m(byte[], int, int)
```

Remember I explicitly added the version 4.3.0.0 crypto algorithm assembly into the GAC. Plus I explictly referenced the dll with both *`#r`* and *`/r:`*. So what gives?

I can see in the *`FusLogVw`* binding logs that *`csi`* is loading the version 4.0.0.0 assembly; in spite of me explicitly insisting on using version 4.3.0.0. *`System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms`* version 4.0.0.0 does not have an *`SHA256Managed`* class.

Please help me figure out how to make *`csi`* use the assembly I tell it to use? Bear in mind, that it uses the right version for code written directly in *`csi`*. So why is it not using the correct assembly version for the exact same code in a third-party library?

Comment: What version of assembly referenced by library?

Comment: Version 4.3.0, @PetSerAl—as far as I can tell by traversing the link I provided above: [_a third-party library_](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NBitcoin) -> [_System.Net.Http -Version 4.3.3_](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Net.Http/4.3.3) -> [_System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates -Version 4.3.0_](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates/4.3.0) -> [_System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms -Version 4.3.0_](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms/4.3.0)

Comment: ... Also, calling the third-party library in VS 2017's C# Interactive window works as expected. And I have confirmed that that one uses v4.3.0.0 of the assembly.

Comment: Are you sure that you are referencing .NET Framework version of `NBitcoin` assembly and not .NET Core one?

Comment: No actually, @PetSerAl. I am not 100% sure. I'm new to .NET. Too new to know what the difference between the two are, I'm afraid. So I only assumed _`csi`_ was using .NET framework. What steps do I take to determine for sure which one is being referenced?

Comment: How you specify `NBitcoin` assembly location to `csi`? Suppose you download `.nupkg` file. Rename it to `.zip`, and unpack `lib` directory. It should have multiple subdirectories. Use `net461` or `netstandard2.0` but not `netcoreapp2.1`.

Comment: _`/r:[path_to_vs_2017_project_dir]\bin\Release\net461\NBitcoin.dll`_. Again, I have confirmed that my app/code works with NBitcoin, because I setup, built and ran it in VS 2017 and in VS 2017's C# Interactive window. So, I'm remembering now that I configured my project to target .NET Framework 4.6.1. _`Shift F6`_ puts all the NBitcoin dependencies (_dlls_) in the _`bin\Release`_  dir of the project. I point _`csi`_ at those same dlls. I will try your _`nupkg`_ suggestion in a moment. But I'm reasonably sure nuget already downloaded a bunch of net461 stuff. But I will check and get back to you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183468/discussion-between-deduper-and-petseral).

Answer (score 0):

***TL;DR***: The *`csi`* newb that I am, after installing the third-party lib for the first time two days ago, I copied its dll plus all its dependencies into a subdirectory of *`csi`*'s bin directory to get *`csi`* to find and load it.

---

***Long Answer***: After bouncing some ideas off of the knowledgeable and helpful C# expert @PetSerAl, [*I eventually figured out what the answer to my original question was*](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/44537545#44537545).

A [*`FusLogVw` Assembly Binding Log Entry*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/fuslogvw-exe-assembly-binding-log-viewer) that I encountered very soon after installing the third-party lib, lead to me putting the third-party dll into a sub directory of *`csi`*'s bin dir. That appears to have inadvertently thwarted *`csi`*'s [*assembly lookup mechanism*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/deployment/how-the-runtime-locates-assemblies) from doing a complete probe of all the locations it should have looked for assemblies. As a result, *`csi`* was finding and referencing its own preinstalled older version of *`System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms`* which is distributed with *`csi`* as part of the original VS 2017 installation.

Consequently, that made *`csi`* ignore both the subsequent *`/r:`* and *`#r`* references to the *`Algorithm`* dll that I was passing it. So it wasn't finding the non-existent *`SHA256Managed`* type in its own, older 4.0.0.0 version of the assembly it had in its bin dir. That's what caused the assembly binder error reported in the original post.

Removing the third-party assembly and co from *`csi`*'s bin subdir did the trick. From there, getting *`csi`* to work correctly with the third-party library was just a matter of launching *`csi`* with [*the right assembly references*](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Interactive-Window#r)...

```
C:\>csi /u:NBitcoin /u:NBitcoin.Crypto /u:System.Security.Cryptography /lib:[my_vs_2017_project_dir]\bin\Release\net461;[my_vs_2017_home_dir]\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\bin\Roslyn\ /r:System.Data.dll /r:System.Drawing.dll /r:System.IO.Compression.FileSystem.dll /r:System.Numerics.dll /r:System.Runtime.Serialization.dll /r:System.Xml.dll /r:System.Xml.Linq.dll /r:Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions.dll /r:[my_vs_2017_project_dir]\bin\Release\net461\Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions.dll /r:[my_vs_2017_project_dir]\bin\Release\net461\Newtonsoft.Json.dll /r:[my_vs_2017_project_dir]\bin\Release\net461\System.Buffers.dll /r:[my_nuget_repo_pkgs_dir]\system.net.http\4.3.4\lib\net46\System.Net.Http.dll /r:[my_vs_2017_project_dir]\bin\Release\net461\System.Net.Requests.dll /r:[my_nuget_repo_pkgs_dir]\nbitcoin\4.1.1.68\lib\net461\NBitcoin.dll /r:[my_nuget_repo_pkgs_dir]\system.security.cryptography.algorithms\4.3.0\lib\net461\System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms.dll /r:[my_nuget_repo_pkgs_dir]\system.security.cryptography.csp\4.3.0\lib\net46\System.Security.Cryptography.Csp.dll /r:[my_nuget_repo_pkgs_dir]\system.security.cryptography.encoding\4.3.0\lib\net46\System.Security.Cryptography.Encoding.dll /r:[my_nuget_repo_pkgs_dir]\system.security.cryptography.primitives\4.3.0\lib\net46\System.Security.Cryptography.Primitives.dll /r:[my_nuget_repo_pkgs_dir]\system.security.cryptography.x509certificates\4.3.0\lib\net461\System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.dll 
Microsoft (R) Visual C# Interactive Compiler version 2.9.0.63208
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Type "#help" for more information.
>
> Console.WriteLine("Hello World! " + new Key().GetWif(Network.Main));
Hello World! L2emt8acTdsGMXzJfAMSARUvKvP8xUCULcQbpiY76EpeyvKyrir2
>
```

I'm pretty sure [*there's a less verbose way*](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/pull/5857) to pass all those *`/r:`* and *`/u:`* options on *`csi`* startup. But just getting it to find and load the correct assemblies is the main thing.